# InputBox in Word 2010 VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, user-input

I'd like to add code to my template where the macro asks "What page is the table on?" and the user can type in the response, i.e., 38.  Afterward, the text, "[Table Page 38]" is inserted, one after the other, into the same, specified Word document.

```
Dim strPageInfo As String
strPageInfo = InputBox("Type page number for table placeholder.")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following snippet will just insert the input number into the text selection. I am not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for.

```
Dim strPageInfo As String
strPageInfo = InputBox("Type page number for table placeholder.")
Selection.TypeText Text:="[Table Page " + strPageInfo + "]";
```

Here's a list of macros for your reference as well. You may be able to find exactly what you are needing to do if this doesn't work.

http://wordribbon.tips.net/C0694_Macros.html

Comment: Many thanks! Line 3 puts me one step closer and that link is mega helpful.